# GTK window, how to get window decoration sizes?

Tags: widget, window, gtk

I am looking for an equivalent of [AdjustWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665(v=vs.85).aspx) function that allows to get widths/heights of window caption and borders.

Do we have this functionality in GTK 3 at all? Seems like not. 
I've looked through all gtk_window_xxx, gtk_widget_xxx and gdk_window_xxx*  functions...

Update:

In principle I am able to determine window-chrome/decoration dimensions as a delta of `gdk_window_get_frame_extents()` and `gtk_widget_get_allocation()` / `gdk_window_get_origin()` but

1. it works only after window appeared on the screen. I need it before that - to calculate initial window position.
2. it is really a hack.

Comment: Did you check the Gdk documentation? I feel if there is functionality for this kind of thing, then it should be in Gdk, not Gtk.

Comment: Yes, I did. That's why the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to Window Manager to decide. 
You can request it by sending a message _NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS as explained in the specification of EWMH (Extended Window Manager Hints):

> ```
> _NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS
>   window = window for which to set _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS
>   message_type = _NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS
> ```
>
> A Client whose window has not yet been mapped can request of the
>   Window Manager an estimate of the frame extents it will be given upon
>   mapping. To retrieve such an estimate, the Client MUST send a
>   _NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS message to the root window. The Window Manager MUST respond by estimating the prospective frame extents and
>   setting the window's _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS property accordingly. The
>   Client MUST handle the resulting _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS PropertyNotify
>   event. So that the Window Manager has a good basis for estimation, the
>   Client MUST set any window properties it intends to set before sending
>   this message. The Client MUST be able to cope with imperfect
>   estimates.
>
> Rationale: A client cannot calculate the dimensions of its window's
>   frame before the window is mapped, but some toolkits need this
>   information. Asking the window manager for an estimate of the extents
>   is a workable solution. The estimate may depend on the current theme,
>   font sizes or other window properties. The client can track changes to
>   the frame's dimensions by listening for _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS
>   PropertyNotify events.

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472648576

So, in two words, you send a _NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS msg to WM (to the root window - it's gdk_get_default_root_window() in case of gdk), then wait for the reply (_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS PropertyNotify), and get the desired data from your window's _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS property.

Comment: Diving one level deeper than GTK/GDK itself is highly non-desirable as it could be DirectFB underneath - no XWindow at all. But as a last resort this may work.

Comment: Unfortunately _NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS is not supported by at least Ubuntu and Mint

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately situation with GTK is even worse than just problem of getting decorations.

The first:

`gtk_window_move(window, x, y)` sets border **frame** position of the window.

And `gtk_window_resize(window, w, h)` sets **client** dimensions of the window.

And there is absolutely no way in GTK API to set border **frame** size programmatically and explicitly. And so there is no way to set window frame position/size of decorated windows.

On Windows and MacOS, using their APIs, that is easy to do, and reliably. But on GTK they only have this:

> `gtk_window_move()`: Begs the window manager to move window to the
>   given position. Window managers are free to ignore this; most window
>   managers ignore requests for initial window positions (instead using a
>   user-defined placement algorithm) and honor requests after the window
>   has already been shown.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the functionality is not there. GTK is agnostic of the decorations that the window manager places on the window; for all that your application is aware of, there may be giant decorations, or there may be none.

What you can do, is use `gtk_window_set_titlebar()` to tell the window manager to let you use your own decorations; then you have full control over their size.

Comment: I don't want my own titlebar or decorations. I just want to know offset of client area (root window widget) from borders of its window. Essentially for `window.move( rectangle, bool client  )` function. Where `client == true` if rectangle is client position on screen and `client == false` if the rectangle defines outer window box.

Comment: There is no way to get this offset in general. You start drawing at zero and the compositor is free to reposition or mangle your window as it wants.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, `AdjustWindowRect()` and `AdjustWindowRectEx()` assume that you are working purely with the default Windows window decorations and, optionally, **one** row of default Windows menus. It's not suitable for custom window decoration or multiple rows of menus; in these cases, you use the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message, which has to be sent to a specific window. `DefWindowProc()` does all the work for you if you just want the defaults. ([Example for multi-row menus.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030911-00/?p=42553) And if you aren't using default Windows menus, then just tell Windows that you aren't; you'll be responsible for positioning everything yourself in this case. GtkMenuBar works on this principle too.)

Since you *want* the default decorations, though, you merely luck out in that Windows provides an `AdjustWindowRect()` function in the first place, and that it will work for the default window decoration because it's provided by Windows.

(It is entirely possible for a program to lie in its `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, but it'd be lying to Windows as well, and Windows does not like a liar. I imagine the same would hold for `_NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS`, though I'm not sure how bad the damage would be in that case.)

So the fact that X11 doesn't have this guarantee that all window managers must follow means you're out of luck in that department. (In fact, I don't think Wayland has such a thing either; does it?) Hell, nothing prevents a window manager from [not having window decorations at all](https://wiki.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/80/Screen-rob-dzen.png). Or you can even [not run a window manager in the first place](http://psx-scene.com/forums/attachments/f167/37444-porting-linux-2-6-ps2-fedora12_xorg_xterm.jpg)!

**In theory,** you could compare the size and position of a window (either the *geometry* of the GdkWindow or the *allocation* of the GtkWindow) with and without CSD to see what space you lost. But I don't know if this is **reliable**. A GTK+ developer will need to confirm.